# Configuring SuperMicro IPMI to use syslog via SMCIPMITool?

Tags: supermicro, ipmitool

Is there a way to use the IPMITool (I'm running version 2.26.0) to remotely configure the syslog settings of an IPMI interface?
I have a few dozen new systems and would prefer to not do this manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found an answer (it's not supported) - although it's 5 years old.

https://www.supermicro.com/support/faqs/faq.cfm?faq=27689